# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.microsoft.sqlserever.jdbc.SQLServerDriver

Tags: java, sql-server-2008, classnotfoundexception

I have an iPad application for restaurant where I need to take live order that is made.

Webservice is provided by .net & for database I have SQL Server 2008.

To get live order, I am using TCP in Java.

When the order is made, I execute one JAR file through .NET.

In JAR file I have java code where I am connecting to database and fetching the data.

**Now to get connected to database, I have to include jar file.**

I am creating JAR file manually by using below statement.

```
jar -cvfm ServerOrders.jar manifest.txt *.class
```

To include another jar file, what I did is added sqljdbc4.jar file in folder and added jar in the above command. New command looks like below.

```
jar -cvfm ServerOrders.jar manifest.txt *.class *.jar
```

But still it gives me `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.microsoft.sqlserever.jdbc.SQLServerDriver`

### ***I think that means, the sqljdbc4.jar is not getting executed.***

Any idea what is going wrong?

---

```
String DB_DRIVER = "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver";
```

---

### ***Answer***

This was happening because I didn't add `sqljdbc4.jar` in `manifest` file.

```
Class-Path : sqljdbc4.jar
```

Once I add above, it didn't give any exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was happening because I didn't add sqljdbc4.jar in manifest file.

```
Class-Path : sqljdbc4.jar
```

Once I add above, it didn't give any exception.